# one controller action does not respond to AllowAnonymous

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've come across some odd authentication behaviour in my MVC application. All controllers inherit from a BaseController, which is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute. Then, in the login page, I decorate actions with [AllowAnoymous].

So, for example, this is freely available whether a user is logged in or not.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
{
    return View();
}
```

If I remove the [AllowAnonymous] attribute from this controller action and try and navigate to it, then I get sent back to the login page, and I see that the URL automatically has a ReturnUrl parameter appened to the QueryString.

However, I have another controller action with the same attribute:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string provider, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
{
    return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = provider, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
}
```

My application absolutely will not render this View for users who aren't logged in, even though it's decorated with [AllowAnonymous]. I can't for the life of my figure out why. However, I have noticed that when you try and navigate to it, no ReturnUrl gets generated.

I guess that's to be expected since it's supposed to allow anonymous users. But it's not. I've tried create a skeleton controller action/view with and without AllowAnonymous and it works as expected.

I'm not using a filter or any custom attribute. What could cause this one action to behave in such a peculiar manner?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the `VerifyCode` method, does it get hit?

Comment: @haim Yes. I've managed to trace the issue to the Layout in the View. Set to null and the controller action works. I think the answerer has the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have call to a child action inside of your `VerifyCode.cshtml` razor view, which is not allowed for anonymous users.